# Graphing picture equations - Curve Lines

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms, graphing-functions, exponential-function

I'm basically trying to recreate the graph picture below. Using a online graphing tool "Desmos":
[image]

I managed to create the equations for the straight lines and circles for the sunset picture.
[image]

However, I tried creating the equations for the two curved lines, but I am having no luck.. I am completely stuck :(
The answer I got trying to solve for the first curve line(green) is y=3 log3(-27x). I don't understand why its so off.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

*Edit: First curve line is y=5+4log3(−x). (Working on restricting the points at the moment)

Comment: I think the curve you want is $y=5+4\log_3(-x)$, not $y=3\log_3(-27x)$.

Comment: Hi; Any more points for that "green line?" That graph is strange. I see (47,0) between (-27,17) and (-12,0)?

Comment: Hello @BarryCipra , that answer appears to be correct. Would you mind explaining how you came to that answer?

Comment: @Asiax3, I posted an answer with explanation.

Comment: @bobbym, what you read as $(47,0)$ is actually $(-17,0)$.  It and $(-12,0)$ are endpoints of the two line segments that meet at $(-3,9)$ (and which the OP renders in blue).

Comment: Incidentally, it looks to me like the three circles are actually centered at $(-9,17)$, not $(-8,17)$.  That is, they appear to be centered directly above the point labeled $(-9,13)$.  (In particular, compare the way they do or don't intersect with the vertical ruled lines at $y=-5$ and $y=-10$ in the original graph versus your Desmos version.)

Comment: Oops, my previous comment should have given the equations of the vertical ruled lines as $x=-5$ and $x=-10$.  Because vertical lines run in the "$y$ direction," I tend to think their equations have the form "$y=$ something."  I make this mistake often enough that I usually catch it, but occasionally it slips by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original picture tells you the curve has the form $y=a+c\log_b(dx)$ for some constants $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$, and that it passes through the points $(-27,17)$, $(-9,13)$, and $(-3,9)$.  Since $27$, $9$, and $3$ are powers of $3$, it makes sense to try $b=3$ for the base of the logarithm (as you did).  If you let $d=-1$ (it has to be negative because your $x$'s are negative and $\log(dx)$ is defined only when $dx$ is positive), then you get

$$\begin{align}
17&=a+3c\\
13&=a+2c\\
9&=a+c\\
\end{align}$$

If you pick any two of these equations and solve for $a$ and $c$, you get $a=5$ and $c=4$.  (For example, subtracting the second equation from the first gives $17-13=(a+3c)-(a+2c)$, which reduces to $4=c$.  Note, there are *three* equations here in only *two* unknowns, so you have to check that the answer really does satisfy all three equations, but of course it does.)